# How to upload a photo to a group?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Here's how I'm attempting to upload a photo (and please tell me if I can improve this):

```
var feedPath = String.Format( "/{0}/photos/", feedId );
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

try {
  var fbUpl = new Facebook.FacebookMediaObject {
    FileName = photoUrl,
    ContentType = "image/jpg"
  };

  var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(photoUrl));
  fbUpl.SetValue(bytes);
  parameters.message = msg;
  parameters.source = fbUpl;

  dynamic fbResult = fbApp.Post(feedPath, parameters);
}
catch (Exception exc) {...}
```

This will upload to the user's wall. However, if I substitute the feedId with the group's id, it does not post to the group. How do we post photos to groups (on behalf of the currently authenticated user)?

Comment: Should Line 1 `var feedPath` say `var photoUrl` instead?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get a manage_group permission...

But there is a bug what I submitted last year : 
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19157

After Facebook fix that, you get a manage_group permission. Then only need to use the group_id as normal user_id to take actions.